# Downloading Outlook Attachments using Python

Tags: python, outlook

I'm new to Python coding and I've seen a couple questions on stack overflow about this topic, but can't seem to get the code to work. I had some code that worked, but made the mistake of writing over that. I'd like to download an attachment from my latest outlook email (I'll use a restrict statement to look for a specific email address at some point). I tried this code and wondered why the error resulted (I have successfully downloaded an attachment from Outlook before, as previously mentioned).

```
Code:

import win32com.client
import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
path=os.path.expanduser("C:\\Test")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test"]
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
#adjust the messages pulled by the python job to those from certain sender, then filter/interact with only those emails that
#are unread, then marks them read

for message in messages:
    if message.UnRead:
        attached_file = message.Attachments
        attachment = attached_file.Item(1)
        for attachment in attached_file:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(path)
            if message.UnRead:
                message.UnRead= False
            break

My Error:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "Cannot save the attachment. You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)
```

```
Other Code: (Executed with no error, but I didn't see the attachment save in the specified location)

import win32com.client
import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
path=os.path.expanduser("C:\\Test")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test"]
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'abc@1234.com'")
#adjust the messages pulled by the python job to those from certain sender, then filter/interact with only those emails that
#are unread, then marks them read

for message in messages:
    if message.UnRead:
        attached_file = message.Attachments
        attachment = attached_file.Item(1)
        for attachment in attached_file:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path + str(attachment))
            if message.UnRead:
                message.UnRead= False
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

`Attachment.SaveAsFile` take a fully qualified **file** name, not folder name. Try

```
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path + "\\" + attachment.FileName)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried adding substituting that into the code and received this new error message:

`code`
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-81df0701b226> in <module>()
     17         attachment = attached_file.Item(1)
     18         for attachment in attached_file:
---> 19             attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path + "\\" + attachment.FileName)
     20             if message.UnRead:
     21                 message.UnRead= False



TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'module' and 'str'

Comment: Is there anything that needs to change with the path variable? I messed around with using \ and \\, but didn't notice any change. The piece of code that restricted the results to the specific email address ran without error, but didn't save the file in the specified location or mark it read.

Comment: Try to introduce a dedicated variable for the attachment file name and log its value. Is it what you expect it to be?